# How to keep iterating through a list with try except?

Tags: python, pandas, selenium

I'm trying to iterate through a csv file with pandas and using selenium to check the list via a website. However, once it hits the exception, it loops on the same item over and over.

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'website.com'

df = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')


def status():
    for ind, row in df.iterrows():
        name = row['id']
        name_id = row['name']
        print(name)
        global name_loc
        name_loc = df[df['name']==name].index.values


        driver.get(url)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="something"]').send_keys(name_id)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="something"]').send_keys(name)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="something"]').send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

        try:
            status = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="something').text
            if status == "true":
                status = "True"
                df.loc[name_loc, "Status"] = status
                print("Status: True")
        except Exception:
            pass
            try:
                global inactive_status
                inactive_status = driver.find_element_by_xpath('something').text
                ins_text = "Registration Information"
                if inactive_status == ins_text:
                    status1 = "False"
                    df.loc[name_loc, "Status"] = status1
                    print("Status: False")

            except Exception:
                status2 = "Invalid"
                df.loc[name_loc, "Status"] = status2
                print(status2)

status()
print(df)
df.to_csv('Report.csv', index=False)
```

It works fine until it hits the exception, then it just loops the same name over and over again. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Add your output

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's happening here, but one of the things that could go wrong in your code is that you're changing the thing you're iterating over, while you're iterating over it. This is dangerous because as you change the dataframe, your loop is modified.

From the docs on `iterrows`:

> You should **never modify** something you are iterating over. This is not guaranteed to work in all cases. Depending on the data types, the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.

This is a "dummy" version of your code, the way I would do it:

```py
import random
import pandas

# Some test dataframe (you can also load one from CSV of course)
df = pandas.DataFrame(
    [{"id": random.randint(0, 100), "name": random.randint(0, 100)} for _ in range(100)]
)


def status(row: pandas.Series):

    # Get some values from this row
    name = row["name"]

    # Do some work

    try:
        if name >= 80:
            raise Exception("Some exception is raised!")
        else:
            print("No problem")
            return True
    except Exception:
        try:
            if name >= 90:
                raise Exception("Even worse!")
            else:
                print("It's ok...")
                return False
        except Exception:
            print("The impossible has happened")
            return "Invalid"


# Apply the status function to every row
df["Status"] = df.apply(status, axis=1)
```